# vb.net dataset looping issue

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, dataset

Having a problem with a small dataset I have created using XML. Just trying to hold a few paths in a single table and use these for an argument when doing a process.start()

This is working great apart from one thing. It picks up each item in my database 5 times for each row. Any idea of what I am doing wrong or a better way about going around this?`

```
            Dim dt As DataTable = ds_MyXMLDatabase.Tables(0)
            Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
            Dim row As DataRow

            startInfo.FileName = "C:\path to my exe.exe"


            For Each row In dt.Rows

                startInfo.Arguments = "/path:""" + row.Item(0) + """ /quiet"

                Process.Start(startInfo)
                Thread.Sleep(1000)

                MsgBox(row.Item(0) + " has been updated!")



            Next row`
```

Comment: Check how many rows really are in the datatable

Comment: @Yuriry is more than likely right, you are looping more than you think because of an extra amount lines it dt.Rows.

Comment: I have one item in my database but it seems to be looping through the XML lines as well. ie the table name and open and close tags. THis is the only way I can think of how it's getting to 5 times when I run it against one item

Comment: Worth noting that the msgbox that shows up is the correct info each time. IE, it keeps saying the same thing 5 times over before moving to the next if there are anymore entries in my database

Comment: WHERE is this code block located?  We kind of lack context here: given the indentation, thats not all that is going on.

Comment: Found that the XML structure was getting a little slow. Have moved away from this to SQLCE instead. Everything is now working fine